# What does "the witless" refer to (many people vs one person)?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "I hope you don't object to my badgering **the witless**."

Source: Diablo II, [Alkor](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Alkor)

Does it refer to the group of people who are witless or to my character in the game (maybe I'm just confusing this with the phrase "the witless one")?

Comment: It doesn't really refer to ***a group** of people who are witless* - just *those/any/all people who are witless* in general (who may or may not be clustered into one or more groups). Same as [*the poor*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+poor+are+always+with+us%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (who *are always with us*) = *those people who are poor.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source observes that the character who speaks this line is notable for "rude humour", and many of his other lines reveal a penchant for insulting his clients. Its precise application can only be ascertained in context; but I think the main point is that is a (weak) pun on a stock line from courtroom dramas, where one lawyer or another is often criticized for *badgering the wit**n**ess*.

Comment: Does it mean then something like "I hope you don't mind that I keep pestering people."?

Comment: @user9657 It might; or it might mean "I hope you don't mind my treating your friends like idiots"; or it might mean "I hope you don't mind my treating you like an idiot". You can't really tell without playing the game and seeing what contexts it shows up in.